# Discretize Integral

Tags: integration, approximation

> With minor edit with respect to the comments.

Suppose I want to evaluate
\begin{align}
\int^{T}_0{e^{-t}x(t)dt}.
\end{align}
However, I can only approximate the continuous function $\mathbb{R}_+ \ni t \mapsto x(t)$ by a discrete sequence $\{x_t : t \in \{0,\Delta t, 2\Delta t, \ldots,N\}\}$ where $\Delta t := T/N$.

- Is the following true (given $N \to \infty$)?
  \begin{align}
  \int^T_0{e^{-t}x(t)dt} \approx \sum^{N}_{t=0}{e^{-t}x_t\Delta dt}
  \end{align}

Comment: It is one way to approximate the integral. For sufficiently nice functions it will work (a.k.a. [Riemann integrable][1]) and you can get arbitrary good approximation by making $\Delta$ smaller. But you probably want something else than T in upper sum limit.

Comment: The link dropped out, here it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral

Comment: Well, replace the upper sum limit by $N$, where this is the number of partitions of the interval $T$, such that $\Delta t= \dfrac{T}{N}$. Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ gives you the integral. For very big(but finite) $N$, you'll have a good approximation to your integral.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks. I think I actually did use the upper limit $N$ and step size $\Delta t = T/N$, but  I didn't put it clearly in the question.

Comment: If $x $ is a bit nicer than continuous then there are better numerical methods.

Comment: Do you have a simple method in mind?